# bash loop processing all files in a directory

Tags: bash, loops

I have this script

```
$AIRLINECODE=xx
for i in $AIRLINECODE_response_*; do
  echo $i
done
```

prints all the files in the directory even if they have a completely different name..

what can i do to limit the for to find only the files that have the wished pattern?

Answer (score 2):

This is because of how you are using the variable name.

When you use `$AIRLINECODE_response_`, bash interprets it as `AIRLINECODE_response_` being the name of the variable. To make it work, use curly braces to specify what is the name: `{AIRLINECODE}_response_`.

All together:

```
AIRLINECODE=xx
for i in ${AIRLINECODE}_response_*; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Also, note that you need to set the variable with `AIRLINECODE=xx`. It is wrong to use `$AIRLINECODE=xx`, because the variables are being set without the leading `$`.

Comment: echo "$i" would be better a bit

Comment: I agree! And in general, I recommend it whenever I can, just now I forgot it :)

Comment: It would be even better to use find (and limit the search to the current directory) and xargs because if you have enough files in the directory ${AIRLINECODE}_response_* is going to fail.